# Laravel migrations seems different from what is coded in migration scheme

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

[image]

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->string('name');
           $table->string('email')->unique();
           $table->string('password');
           $table->rememberToken();
         $table->timestamps();
    });
}
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
}


 }
```

I have this code and it shows different data in phpmyadmin when i run PHP ARTISAN MIGRATE
photo

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that your screenshot is of the `migrations` table itself, rather than of the `admins` table.

The `migrations` table is used by Laravel to determine which (if any) migrations have been applied to your database.  From there it can determine which migrations still need to be run.

I'd suggest that you refresh the page and then view the structure of the `admins` table (PHPMyAdmin doesn't auto refresh).

Answer (score 1):

Your given screen shot seems to be of 'migrations' table instead of 'admins' table. Please refresh and check in 'admins' table. Your migration code is correct and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this: I have send a form to a server and it eventually have written all tables to database.